# Can't load model data into create() function (ERROR: Call to a member function with() on array)

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error when trying to load a table into my create() function so that the user can select from a list of team_names in the create user page: `Call to a member function with() on array`

Here is my UserController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Game;
use App\User;
use App\Team;

...

public function create()
  {
    $pagetitle = 'Create User';
    $teams = Team::orderBy('team_name', 'asc')->get();

    if(auth()->user()->user_type !== 'admin'){
      return redirect('/')->with('error', "You do not have access to the game you attempted to view.");
    }

    return view('pages.admin.users.create', compact('pagetitle')->with('teams', $teams));
  }
```

Here is my create.blade.php

```
  @if(count($teams) > 0)
    @foreach($teams as $team)
      <option value="{{$team->id}}">{{$team->team_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
  @else
    <p>No teams found...</p>
  @endif
```

Relationships really should not matter in this case, though I do have all of them properly set up.

For context: I'm creating a "User", but loading all of the "Team" names.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compact('pagetitle')->with('teams', $teams)` is wrong.

`compact('pagetitle')` returns an `array`. there is no function called `with()` on array.

To returns an array contains both `pagetitle` and `teams` you can use compact.

```
compact('pagetitle', 'teams');
```

That's it.

So,

```
return view('pages.admin.users.create', compact('pagetitle', 'teams'));
```

Comment: Silly mistake, my bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use compact() or with() to pass object to view.

```
return view('pages.admin.users.create',compact('pagetitle','teams'));
OR
return view('pages.admin.users.create')->with('pagetitle',$pagetitle)->with( 'teams',$teams);
```